# setup internet connection through pppoe

Tags: networking, raspbian-wheezy

i'm new to raspi/debian. I need to connect my raspi, for the first time, to internet. As the PC i need to establish an pppoe link to my router as required from my internet service provider. I don't know what's package precisly required, i read something like i need pppoeconf package, but i'd like to expand deeply my knowledge about these, before install something. An other question is, i have to install driver or they are included?
I have debian wheezy 7.0.

Comment: Does your router not hand you just a plain old tcp/ip connection?  Sounds like it may be time for an upgraded router...

Answer (score 3):

We would need to know what router it is before we know whether you need to install drivers.
Do you connect to the router using Ethernet ? If you do, you don't need drivers.

you will need a few packages -

```
ppp
pppoe
```

Optionally you can also install pppoeconf to configure the connection

If you want to know more about the package, `apt-cache show ppp` will show you what the package does.